# How to update a clicked element using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

kinda new to React and I am looking to use useState but only to be applied to the clicked element. For example:

```
const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState({background: "green"});
```

in my function I have something like this:

```
function updateBackground(){
let updateColor = {background: "blue"};
setBackgroundColor(updateColor);
}
```

then in my return JSX code I have

```
{subButtons.map(function(subButton, index){
   return (<div key={index} onClick={updateBackground} style={backgroundColor}>{subButton}</div>)
 })}
```

but this will apply this function to all generated elements of the .map method.

How can I update my code to be applied to the clicked only element?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by the "clicked only element"? it'll only change the colour on the one you click

Comment: nope, it applies the blue color to all of the elements that the map function will create.

Comment: see answer Peter please

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to manage the discrete state of multiple children in the parent.  @Denis Stukalov answered the question by suggesting keeping a corresponding array of state per child. This can work, but I find that it rarely scales well in the real world.

I would suggest keeping track of the state inside the button itself.

```js
const BackgroundButton = (props) => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = React.useState({background: 'green'});
  const updateBackground = () => setBackgroundColor({background: 'blue'});
  return <div onClick={updateBackground} style={backgroundColor} {...props} />
};

const App = () => ['button1', 'button2', 'button3'].map(
  (subButton, index) => (
    <BackgroundButton key={index}>{subButton}</BackgroundButton>
  )
);
```

[See this in action in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/tupton/pen/zYrOWGp?editors=0010).

Answer (score 1):

You should use array instead single background object. Like this:

```
const subButtons = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']
const [backgroundColors, setBackgroundColor] = useState(subButtons.map(() => { return { background: "green" } }))

function updateBackground(index){
  let newBackgroundColors = [...backgroundColors]
  newBackgroundColors[index] = { background: "blue" }
  setBackgroundColor([...newBackgroundColors])
}

return (subButtons.map(function(subButton, index){
 return (<div key={index} onClick={()=>updateBackground(index)} style={backgroundColors[index]}>{subButton}</div>)
}))
```

See in playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s505358

Answer (score 0):

```
const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("green");

function updateBackground(){
  let updateColor = "blue"
  setBackgroundColor(updateColor);
}
```

try this instead

Comment: maybe you have misspelled something in there? this way I am assigning the variable 'blue' into variable 'updateColor', so it gives me an error message 'blue is not defined'

Comment: it doesn't work, because backgroundColor is being used by style={} so style is expecting a valid CSS.

Comment: ok try changing that `style={{ backgroundColor }}` or `style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor}} `

Comment: the same behavior applies to all elements, not only to the clicked one.

Comment: ah my bad I see what's happening now. you could create each mapped item as a child component that holds it's own state and when you pass props down it renders them correctly. let me know if you want more code for that